# Load XML from string in libxml++ in C++

Tags: c++, libxml2

Does anyone familiar with libxml++ know if it's possible to load the XML document from a string instead of a file? Alternately, if it can load a document directly from a web page, that would do.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for either [xmlpp::Parser::parse_memory](http://library.gnome.org/devel/libxml++/stable/classxmlpp_1_1Parser.html#abbbf646035570f1aa5366558dfc2ae01) or [xmlpp::DomParser::parse_memory](http://library.gnome.org/devel/libxml++/stable/classxmlpp_1_1DomParser.html#a2110398d5a19320e7bbe65e0edb2ab9c).

Each of those classes also have a `parse_stream` method which take a `std::istream` if that is more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, ticpp::DomParser::parse_memory should do it.